# Links to the pages do not work in new tabs

Tags: python, web-scraping

I wanted to compile a database using Python + Selenium and Mongo by having links from this website https://www.zvg-portal.de/index.php?button=Termine%20suchen (based on certain parameters in the search forms and dropdown menus) but after I enter any mandatory dropdown fields the links to results and to the page itself resulting in "error".

I understand that there is a potential issue with the php backend of the website. Is there a way to simulate the request to the website so that it returns the requested webpage?

Comment: Please post the code you are using. And as with all web scraping, you need to simulate the browser by sending the same headers and all appropriate form fields, including anything that is created/managed with JS such as a CAPTCHA.

Comment: Tried to insert the code but it is too big. Essentially I do not have issues with the code, it gathers information that I need. the only issue is that the links that are gathered can not be opened in a new window resulting in an "error". Even if you copy-paste the link from the browser it results in the same error. There is an issue with how to simulate PHP request I guess but I cant figure it out.

Comment: There is nothing special about PHP in this regard. You are making an HTTP request, it is going to an HTTP server, probably Apache, which happens to be offloading it to PHP, but could be Java, JS or anything else.

Comment: “the only issue is that the links that are gathered can not be opened in a new window” - Are you web scraping and trying to pass that HTML to a browser? That’s where your problem probably is. The browser is probably missing something such as a session cookie. Try this: ignore scraping, and try opening one of the links from the origin site in a private browsing window to see if it renders as you expect.